# Return Doctrine_Null Object when insert record in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am new to Symfony, i am facing an issue when i tried to insert a record. Here is part of my code at FormRequestDao.php:

```
public function saveFormRequest(FormRequest $formRequest, $formList, $entitlements) {
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();        
    print_r($formRequest);
    $formRequest->save();
    ...
    return $formRequest;
}
```

I always  get the value "note" in null/blank, it just a normal textbox.
Here is the partial result of print_r($formRequest):

```
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => Doctrine_Null Object
            (
            )

        [product_type_id] => 1
        [date_inserted] => 2017-05-31
        [item_number] => 0002
        [description] => This is a product 1.
        [note] => Doctrine_Null Object
            (
            )

    )
```

And the value of "note" has been captured in productApplicationService.php:

```
public function insertProduct(ProductParameterObject $productAssignmentData) {
    print_r($productAssignmentData);
    return $this->saveFormRequest($productAssignmentData);        
}
```

Any clue for me?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any return value inside saveFormRequest

Comment: there is a "return $formRequest;" at the end of the function. Let me update my function again.

Comment: Are you writing a REST API or a simple mvc with symfony where you want to pass to your twig file the new entity?

Comment: just normal MVC with form submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a response for your twig file you need to return this for example

```
   return $this->render(':yourtwig.twig', [
        'yourEntity' => $this->saveFormRequest($productAssignmentData)
    ]);
```

Comment: Tried, but no luck. Just wondering why others elements are posted with value, but not the element "note"....

Comment: I found the issue, i missed out to define the "note" at AbstractProductAllocationService.php file.